# Oracle Apex: ROWS PER PAGE not showing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid, but I don't find the ROWS PER PAGE option. I want to set max number of rows to 5 or 10

The option is not available neither in the attributes nor the actions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 5.1 any more, but - in recent Apex versions, it is in [Actions - Format - Rows per page]:

[image]

---

Or, in Interactive Report's "Attributes", if you enable "Rows per page selector" under the "Search bar" group of properties, you get a separate item right next to the search bar:

[image]

---

I hope at least one of these options is available in Apex 5.1 as well.